# Vanity URL tacking in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to track vanity url in which PDF is present in GA.

For e.g. I have vanity url

xyz.com/study when user click a url opens.

Click of vanity url opens a page in PDF format.

below is the url. 
             http://example.com/sites/default/files        /course.pdf?utm_source=vanityurl&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=pdf%20tracking.
I want to track utm parameter in GA

Can any one suggest hot to do that in GA or using Google Tag Manager

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have 2 options based on how this vanity URL actually functions:

1 = If the vanity URL is *always* accessed by clicking a link, you could write an onclick function for all links to the URL which fires a virtual pageview and sets the source, campaign and medium.  something like this:

```
<script>
function trackpdf(){
  ga('set', 'campaignName', 'pdf tracking');
  ga('set', 'campaignSource', 'vanity url');
  ga('set', 'campaignMedium', 'email');
  ga('set', 'location', 'http://example.com/study');
  ga('send', 'pageview')
}
</script>
<a href="http://example.com/study" onclick="trackpdf();">view pdf</a>
```

2 = If the vanity URL has some server side code sat behind it, you could use the measurement protocol to send a pageview.  This would mean creating a valid GA HTTP request and sending it using server side code.  Check out the [Google Docs for more info](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/).

Comment: Thanks Tom, for the suggestion but the problem is that after clicking the vanity url PDF page open. but this PDF page is not getting detected as page and  no event and tag are getting fired on it . Also the GTM  preview mode is also not working on opened PDF page.

Comment: Also, suppose if vanity url is part of email campaign and if a user click the vanity url in the mail then how will it work ?

Comment: Sameer, how exactly does the vanity URL redirect to the PDF document?  Is it using htaccess rewrite rules or is there a server side page doing the redirect?

Comment: It is a one of the many vanity url  we are running. In this we send email to people with the vanity url link in the email. We want to check which vanity url have been clicked by email receiver. It is server side page. In a email when user click on vanity url link. It get pass to the server on which it its present or hosted and the PDF opens.

Comment: OK, understood.  You should use option 2 in my answer then: send an event on the server side using the Measurement Protocol.  To use the MP you create an HTTP request that sends the data in the normal format that GA would send in the front end.  You need to read the docs to understand it, there's not a short answer I can give here.  In addition you'll encounter the issue that any new visitors to your site won't have a _ga cookie generated yet (no CID available) so you'll have to work out a method to resolve that too.